# Tensorflow <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'

Tags: python, lambda, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to run the code probably written for a previous Tensorflow version. I have fixed many `unexpected keyword argument`errors related to keywords mismatch

Now I get `<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'`

But there isn't *partition_info* keyword in my code.

Here the piece of code that causes the problem:

```
final_fully_connected = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    hidden_layer_three,
    2,  
    weights_initializer=lambda i, dtype: tf.truncated_normal([38912, 512], stddev=0.1),
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the function you provide as the `weights_initializer` argument should expect a keyword argument `partition_info`, but your lambda does not.

See the `_initializer` function defined in [ones_initalizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L76) for an example of the function signature expected for `weights_initializer`:

```
  def _initializer(shape, dtype=dtype, partition_info=None):
    return constant_op.constant(1, dtype=dtype, shape=shape)
```

In that same file, if you look down at `uniform_unit_scaling_initializer` and `variance_scaling_initializer`, you can see examples of weights initializers that actually use the `partition_info` argument; but most of the initializers in the file just ignore it.

Comment: partition_info seems an optional attribute, and is unclear to me where and why should add it in my code. Could you give me more details? thanks

Comment: instead of lambda, use a local function which has an additional "partition_info" attribute (which is ignored)

Comment: @AndreaF: Just add `partition_info=None` to the arguments of your lambda. I.e. `weights_initializer=lambda i, dtype, partition_info=None: tf.truncated_normal([38912, 512], stddev=0.1)`

Comment: unfortunately  same error(but longer execution before crash at same point)

Comment: @AndreaF: If you're getting the same error, that means something is passing `partition_info` to a function that's not accepting it. If you made the change I suggested, then there must be another weights_initializer which you provide somewhere else which doesn't take the necessary arguments.

Comment: as I have said there isn't any partition_info in my original code

Comment: @AndreaF: which is the whole problem! The functions you write for this need to take `partition_info`!

Comment: I have tried both with and without this is the problem

Comment: if your lambda has an argument `partition_info`, then you shouldn't get "<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'` error

Comment: maybe something is wrong with my syntax. Could someone write this line code in a supposedly right form?

Comment: @Kundor the your previous suggestion  `weights_initializer=lambda i, dtype, partition_info=None: tf.truncated_normal([38912, 512], stddev=0.1)` causes error *non-default argument follows default argument*

Comment: @AndreaF: Only if you've changed it around, since the default argument (`partition_info=None`) clearly follows the non-default arguments (`i` and `dtype`) in what you've pasted.

Comment: @Kundor I have copied the line exactly as written.

Comment: I have found the issue, a damn invisible char! Now works! Thank you